# How do I record a video with a file size larger than 4GB on Galaxy S4 exfat SD card?

Tags: sd-card, camera, video-recording

I've searched quite a bit and called Samsung tech support who didn't have any documentation on this issue. They all say that there isn't a limit on how much video you can record. I want to record class lectures, they run about 2 hours long. I set up the camera and tap record. Camera runs properly for about 30 minutes then says "Maximum File Size Reached" and stops recording. This happens to occur at a file size of 4GB about where you'd expect fat32 issues to occur. This is a Samsung SGH I337 from ATT Android Version 4.2.2

Here's what I've tried. The camera is set to record to the SD card. The SD card is exfat formatted. I can drop a 16GB .iso onto the card from my windows 7 computer through the phone via the usb cord with no issues. This leads me to believe there isn't a file size limitation from the format of the card. The SD card is NOT full it is a 65GB card with 40GB free.

Does anyone know of an app or a tweak that will let me record unlimited video within the real constraints of my hardware, 50GB's of 1080P video at a time or until battery failure?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the video quality settings to a lower rez and try again
Leave it 16:9 At 1280x720 instead of 1920x1080. I would imagine your content will be watched on computers and iPads etc and not in imax theatres. You might get 2 hours out of that.

It is a stupid limitation .
I'm in the same boat so I'll keep looking. Maybe there are some developer options to fiddle with.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not about the file size but about the video length. Devices that can record videos longer than 30 minutes are classified as video-recorders in the European Union and are subject of higher import taxes. That is why manufactures of smartphones and compact cameras limit the maximum video length to 28-29 minutes - to avoid those higher taxes (and som eof them do so not only for EU market but for other contries for simplicity in production). So reducing resolution or bitrate will not solve the issue.

*PS. It is rumored that this regulation will be cancelled soon so the future smartphones will be "allowed" to record videos longer than 30 minutes. But as of now (Feb 2019) I couldn't find any reliable information about how soon it's going to happen*