# How much space do I need for 1hr of 1080p video?

Tags: camera, video-recording

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 edge with 10GB of space free. I'd like record roughly 1hr continuously using the standard camera app.

Do you see any problem with this?

Comment: Depends very much on the camera app used and which codec/compression that is using, no general answer on that. And yes, often there's a time limit so recording automatically stops at e.g. 30min – which some apps work around by creating multiple files for the same recording (imitating a stop/record).

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57417/how-do-i-record-a-video-with-a-file-size-larger-than-4gb-on-galaxy-s4-exfat-sd-c

Answer (score 2):

1hr of 1080p footage shouldn't take up 10GB. the data amount changes based on a few factors such as frame rate and bit rate. 60fps takes up more space than 30fps. higher bit rates also take up more storage space. It could anywhere from a few hundred MB to 2 GB perhaps. It also depends on the storage format the video is saved in. Some formats use different forms of compression, some are more effective than others.

Comment: On my smartphone, I have a less than 4 minutes footage which is almost 1Gb. One hour would be more than 15 Gb.

Answer (score 1):

Record one minute and check how much storage it takes and duplicate by 60

Comment: Are there any other limitations? Google is reporting sporadically that there are artificial time limits. I don't have the time/battery to test these limits (massively disorganised)

Comment: i dont think there are. i suggest you check the camera app settings.

Comment: This seems like a good idea but it's not. 1 minute of a dark environment will take up less space than others. It's a good indicator, though, but not perfect.